# Saving bounding box coordinates for each frame in a video

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, vision

I have a video from a camera with humans on the scene. I need to go through each frame of that video and **manually** save the coordinates (go through each frame and draw the square around each human) of the bounding box of the detected humans on the scene and the coordinate of the center of the head - so basically, `top-left`, `bottom-right`, `head-center` coordinates. The bounding box has to be a square.

An additional program will then read a file with coordinates of the square and center of head and the frame number, and extract the boxes as an image.

For anybody that has experience with computer vision - is there any open-source software that can accomplish what I am requesting? If not, what technology would you recommend building this tool on? Any starter code?

Comment: Do you need to detect just faces (i.e. the faces are within you bounding box) or entire bodies (and then the center of the head afterwards)?

Comment: Also, is the camera stationary or moving?   If the camera (and therefore the background) is static, you can perhaps use background subtraction techniques.

Comment: this question is far too general. being able to detect objects (humans) is one of the major challenges in computer vision. tracking them (is that needed?) is another difficult problem. Please add more details on the scene (indoor/outdoor, point of view, static occlusions, density of people, etc..)

Comment: I want to MANUALLY do this - i.e. I will go through each frame and draw the bounding box myself. Later, an additional program will then read a file with coordinates of the square and center of head and the frame number, and extract the boxes as an image. The extracted images will serve as my training dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any programs that can do specifically this, but I think it is an easy problem and you can code it yourself in no time.

As you are in the computer vision field you must be used to OpenCV. You can use it to extract the frames from a video and to select the box and head center.

Here are some links that can help you out:

[Extract video frames](http://answers.opencv.org/question/6241/how-to-extract-frames-from-avi-video/)

[Detect mouse events](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/mouse-events.html)